# Does windsurfing experience help me to learn kitesurfing?

Tags: water-sports, windsurfing, kitesurfing

I have some experience in windsurfing, meaning that I can perform the basic moves and handle the board and sail under normal to slightly difficult conditions. I have always been interested in Kitesurfing but had never had the opportunity to do it so far. I would like to try it out, but I would really be disappointed if I had to start from scratch and climb the whole learning curve again.

Will my windsurfing experience give me any advantage over complete beginners when starting kitesurfing?

Are there other sports that could be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding and 'feel' of waves and swell will almost almost certainly help, as will experience of identifying gusts coming in.

Being able to carve a board will also be useful.

Overall, while you will still need to learn how to handle the kite, your experience windsurfing will shorten your time to proficiency.